# How to open links in a native web browser (common suggestion did not work)?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

PhonegGap (Adobe® PhoneGap™ Build) opening external links take very long and will not be opened in the native phone browser.

Well this is my problem. First of all, if I click a external link within my app it takes very long until the result gets displayed. So for example if I click a link nothing happens a few seconds then the site will be displayed within the app itself. Every normal user would think there is a problem if it takes so long. Looks like the complete site gets loaded first before it gets displayed what is fine for my app but not for external links.

**Native Browser problem**

However, I'm not a real friend of opening external web links into the apps view anyway. I like to get them opened in the native browser of my phone.

There exist several questions and suggestions to this problem already, many of them so old that maybe outdated, many of them even on stack overflow. But to summarize the answers. The recommend to open Links not directly but over click event, prevent the defaults and than opening a new window with javascript window.open('http://www.myurl.nl', '_system');

And also the recommend to set  tags.
For the _system you will need the inAppBrowser Plugin what is available with `<gap:plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" version="0.1" />` on Adobe Build in config.xml.

Well as a result my links get opened in a new Window (not tab) on any desktop and mobile browsers. But when I build it as app and start it on Android for example it always opens the links in the APP not the native browser. No matter what setting combinations I tried. I see no difference on each try. (Testing currently Android but Iphone test will follow.

May somebody can give me an up-to-date answer on the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently developed a mobile app using PhoneGap Build, so you can be sure the following solutions are uptodate.

No matter you want to use web view or external browser, you need to add the `inAppBrowser` plugin to `config.xml`

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser">
```

Now, if you want to open native (external) web browser use this command:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');
```

If you want to open embedded browser use this one:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

to manage the delay between when the user action and appearance of the embedded browser, you can use `loadstop` event to show the browser after it gets loaded completely:

```
    Mask('show'); /* a function to show some loading animation*/
    var inAppBrowser = window.open(link, '_blank','hidden=yes');
    inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
        //show after complete load
        inAppBrowser.show();
        Mask('hide'); /* hide the loading mask*/

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and give a feedback – what I see from now the `<gap:plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" version="0.1" />` what I got from https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/673 is different to your  `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser">` – I need to check out how does plugins work with adobe build and how to check if it was loaded correctly. Also the loadstop listener is a good idea, as for now I just used a 2 second timeout.

Comment: @TheMAn The `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` is the official plugin and if you want to mention the version add this: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />`

Comment: Hello org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser did fix the problem, thank you, the other plugin somehow did not work. I fixed the versiond in the meantime. Well and since inAppBrowser I do not need a Loader for external pages anymore, while the open directly after clicking in the native browser. Thanks

Comment: @TheMAn I'm glad it works for you. So please accept the answer.

Comment: sorry, I did not know how to do it and needed to google it first. Is accepted now. However I just can accept it voting is still not available for me since I have 15 reputations and it looks like I won't ever get them cause somebody is always just downvoting my wuestions :D Thank you so far

Answer (score 1):

In your config.xml, add:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

Then for the links, use:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com">Example page</a>
```

At least this is what has worked for me.

Comment: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />` is correct that worked for me. org.li8... what should do the same did not work.

But "_blank" is not correct to open the nativ browser, this will cause a different behaviour from system to system (Android, IOS, WinPhone) depending on access origions. PhoneGap promoted a Blog explaining exactly this problem. Even target="" is not the right way, you can find it in the inAppBrowser manual. The only correct way is "_system" and a window.open(… '_system) call within javascript to be sure that inAppBrowser opens a nativ browser.